# Spooling only DBMS_OUTPUT

Tags: plsql, spool

I have a procedure I need to spool the output from this procedure into a new sql file.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE lock_users_prep
AS
  username varchar2(60);
 BEGIN
    FOR user IN (SELECT username
                FROM dba_users WHERE username NOT IN (SELECT name FROM hr.katastr_users))
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('alter user "'||user.username||'" account lock;');
  END LOOP;
END;
 /


set heading off arraysize 1 pages 0 feedback off echo off verify off
SPOOL lockall.sql
  EXEC lock_users_prep
SPOOL OFF lockall.sql
```

But in my file lockall.sql I still have the first row like this:

```
> EXEC lock_users_prep
alter user "SYSTEM" account lock;
alter user "SYS" account lock;
alter user "OLAPSYS" account lock;
```

I need to get rid of the first line. Any ideas what set command to use?

Comment: termout off didn't help, still getting the same output

Comment: What are you using to run the procedure?  SQL*Plus?

Comment: Im using SQL Developer

Comment: Yeah, if I run it in SQL*Plus its working fine, thanks for idea.

Comment: Works in SQL*Plus if you add "set serveroutput on" and fix the spool off syntax error (no filename needed).  Perhaps there's a setting in SQL Developer to control what gets output?

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but why not simply do execute immediate ... instead of dbms_output.put_line(...)?

Answer (score 2):

If you use spooling to create files you are at the mercy of the host and the current environment.  For example many of the "set" commands in SQL*Plus.  The DBMS_OUTPUT buffer may also be limited which risks an exception if you send too much data.

The correct way to write files from PL/SQL is to use the UTL_FILE package.  This will give you more control over your output and avoid problems such as in this question.